# Modelling Biased APD In Integrator Circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit, photodiode, modeling, integrator, small-signal

I want to model a biased APD (Avalanche Photodiode) whose current output feeds into an integrator. For the IC I will be using, TI recommends the following configuration for an unbiased photodiode.

[image: TI Integrator Configuration For Unbiased Photodiode]

Does the complexity of the configuration scale if the photodiode is an APD? I am thinking for a biased APD I may be able to use the following representation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdTR8H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, sensor Resistance R, and sensor capacitance C, seem very general. What are their meanings in the context of an APD? More specific resistances and capacitances are given for
this model of an unbiased junction photodiode.

[image: Small-signal equivalent circuit of Junction Photodiode]

My end goal is to use the simplest possible model for an APD that will still yield sufficiently accurate results in my simulations of the IC. The specific information I have is the sensor output and corresponding reverse bias voltage.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Look in the data sheet for the APD for R and C. Almost certainly C will be quoted and R can probably be estimated.

Comment: There is not a datasheet given for the APD I am using. It is not publicly available

Comment: Then you need to speak with the supplier to get the information. Nobody here is going to be able to guess values.

Comment: What does your simulation need to accurately model?  Simple models like this will not fully capture all features of an APD (e.g. you have nothing in your model for gain or multiplication noise), but may be good enough for other purposes. Be specific about what you mean by accurate.

Comment: @ColeFehr Can you ask a specific question?